# IoC logger with parameters

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ioc-container

I'm currently playing around with the IoC concept (with a WPF app) and I haven't decided on the tool I'll used with it just yet as I'm still trying to get the grasp of it but I'm confused as to how this would be configured regarding the specific parameters each component.

I understand how you define the relevant library in the config file and how it will determine which one should be used by the app and what its lifespan should be but what about each library requiring its own specific set of parameters.

Where do you get these from and when do you pass them on?

Taking your typical logger for example.

I have the following interface:

```
public interface ILogger
{
    void Write(string message);
}
```

I have the logger class itself:

```
public class Logger : ILogger
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public Logger (ILogger logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public void Write(string message)
    {
        _logger.Write(message);
    }
}
```

I then define multiple loggers each requiring their own parameter, so I implemented the following:

**a) database logger:** where a connection string is required so that I can log my message to a database.

```
public void LoggerDb: ILogger
{
    public void Write(string message)
    {
    }

    public ConnectionString {get; set;}
}
```

**b) file logger:** where a filename is required so that I can log my message to the relevant log file.

```
public void LoggerFile: ILogger
{
    public void Write(string message)
    {

    }

    public Filename {get; set;}
}
```

**c) console logger:** where no parameter is required as I just want to output my message to a console window.

```
public void LoggerConsole: ILogger
{
    public void Write(string message)
    {
    }
}
```

In my console test app, I've got the following code in the Program.cs:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string logTypeId = "d";
    ILogger logType;

    if (logTypeId == "d")
    {
        logType = new LoggerDb("Data Source=....");
    }
    else if (logTypeId == "f"
    {
        logType = new LoggerFile("c:\\mylog.txt");
    }
    else
    {
        logType = new LoggerConsole();
    }

    Logger logger = new Logger(logType);

    logger.Write("Message 1");
    logger.Write("Message 2");
    logger.Write("Message 3");
}
```

I understand this is not how the code would be if I used an IoC tool. I'm just trying to highlight what I'm trying to achieve and I'm trying to get answers to the following questions:

1. Can this be achieved using an IoC tool i.e. pass specific parameter depending on the logger type that's used/defined in the IoC section of the app.config?
2. Is this the correct approach i.e. Having specific loggers with their own constructors parameters? If not, can you explain why and what should be the correct approach. I don't mind the IoC tool you use. I just want to understand how this should be done.
3. Where should these additional parameters be stored in the app.config?

Comment: "I understand this is not how the code would be if I used an IoC tool." This is incorrect. What you're doing is a valid approach, even if you use a DI library. Your `Main` method is the [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/) and that's the place you would also configure your DI library. In the case of using a DI library, your code might look exactly the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, note that in order to implement DI via an IoC, it is by no means required to configure your container in a configuration file (although it's certainly an option and many containers support it).

Most IoC containers these days also allow you to specify your setup in code. So I guess the answer is: it really depends on the IoC container you plan to use. My opinion: avoid xml-based configuration if you can; it's often a pain to maintain and brings little value if you ask me. In your code-based configuration you can still refer to configuration parameters from app.config or other.

You can also turn the question around: is it a requirement to have the container configuration in a separate file (and why)? If yes, look for a container that supports this well. But most do.

Some examples of configuration using a code-based DSL:

- Autofac modules: http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/configuration/modules.html
- StructureMap: http://structuremap.github.io/registration/registry-dsl/

Some examples of xml configuration:

- Autofac: http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/configuration/xml.html
- Spring.NET container: http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/objects.html
- structuremap: http://docs.structuremap.net/configuring-structuremap/structuremap-xml-configuration/

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I'll have a look at your links but what would you use instead of xml-based configuration files and why does it bring little value. Also when you say code-based configuration, do you just mean accessing data using the `Properties.Default.xxx`?

Comment: I forgot to ask one thing in my question. In the event of the FileLogger for example, it is ok to change the "Filename" property at run-time rather than through the constructor in the event I need to change my filename at run-time i.e. create a filename based on a specific process, where each process would have its own log file with a different filename but use the same logger? Thanks.

Comment: I highly recommend reading the documentation on Autofac modules (check the examples). As to your question, that is really a design question that has little to do with dependency injection.

Comment: I'm not familiar with any of them so I'm finding it confusing (for now) and samples provided by structure map as not working but hopefully things will click and I'll figure it out. My main objective is that I want to be able to switch libraries such as the logger example above or add new ones at run time without having to recompile our app. As a matter of interest, do you know the difference between the likes of StructureMap and MvvmLight simple IoC?

Comment: SimpleIoC is a very basic container, it has no advanced lifecyle management or interception capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

It depends ;)

1. I can't speak for all DependencyInjection Tools, but many of them should support this functionality.
2. I don't see anything that speak against this. If you want to call different Loggers explicitly, you can do this. But you can also use some kind of LogListeners. One for DB, one for File and so on. And your Logger just delegates the LogMessage to all Loggers. But this depends on what you want or need ;)
3. This also depends on the implementation of the Logger. It's common to store the  ConnectionString in the config. The other parameters are too specific, but you you can store them in config, too.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, but I don't want to call different logger at the same time. I just want to allow to switch from one to the other if required.